# Overwrite CSS of Instaemail Popup

Tags: javascript, css, button, plugins, popup

I am using [instaemail](http://www.instaemail.com/) on my website for sending a post by email and I am trying to customize popup window, but seems that I can not overwrite class or I don't know how to do it. Same popup you can find on link above if you click on email (try it)

I had success with changing wraper color and ID by putting in style.css

```
div#pf-email-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(09, 85, 3, 0.50);
}
```

but how to change (overwrite URL)

```
.email-sprite{
  background: url('/images/email/email-app-sprite.png') no-repeat;
}
```

or change color of

```
.pf-email label {
  color:#356da9; }
```

So the CSS in style.css would overwrite default CSS of Instamail script

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `!important` from css.

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

```
.email-sprite {
     backgroun: url('your url') no-repeat !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried that already. It is not problem with priority since it is not showing new URL nowhere when I inspect element. It is probably by calling the class for example `span.email-sprite` but I am not sure how exacly

Comment: if you are not seeing the new css rule when you inspect the element, double check the css rule is correct.

Comment: dammn this is so vague. the problem is that the popup box is an IFRAME to which you cannot change anything from. Im trying to hide the ads that come after to mail is sent to no avail